# Provide inputs to nested subcomponents

Tags: angular, input, components

I am building a custom compound component in Angular. Let's say it is a component A which contains component B, and so on - down to component D - being the deepest one. `A > B > C > D`

I want to offer an `@Input` on the component A which would accept a `TemplateRef<any>` from outer world and pass it down to component D. Components B and C don't make any use of that template, just to be clear.

Do I have to create intermediate inputs on components B and C, or can I somehow (through DI?) query component A from component D, as if saying "hey A, do you have a template for me?"

(This actually applies not only to TemplateRef inputs).

Comment: I think this is the only option you have. Lets see if anyone else can suggest some better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each component have is own Injector in the Injector Tree of your app.

So you can request the parent ComponentA in the ComponentD constructor then request it after initialization ( aka after the OnInit of ComponentD )

The syntax is :

```
export class AppComponentD implements OnInit  {
  something: any;
  constructor (private myParentAd: AppComponentA) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.something = this.myParentAd.getSomething();
  }

  ...
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2jors) demonstring this

Note:  if you try to create a ComponentD with no ComponentA parent it will throw an error. You can is [@Optional decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) in constructor to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! The @Optional decorator would be needed mostly for unit tests I guess? Can that technique be safely used to pass Output emissions as well?

Comment: in test case you could provide a mock of the AppComponentA will configuring your testBed. Im not sure of what you mean by "used to pass Output emissions as well"

Comment: What I mean is the Component D instead of emitting and bubbling up intermediate events, could procedurally call Component A like: `this.myParentA.doSomethingOnEventFromD()`

Comment: Oh yeah you can do that =)